# Correct use of device_type in OpenACC

Tags: gpgpu, gpu, openacc

I have a `for` loop and I want to parallelize it with OpenACC if the target hardware is NVIDIA, or run it serially when the target hardware is AMD. I tried the following:

```
#pragma acc loop \
    device_type(tesla) parallel \
    device_type(radeon) seq
for (int z = 0; z < size_z; ++z)
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

Compiled with: `pgc++ -std=c++11 -O4 -ta=tesla -Minfo:accel main.cpp`

But on the parallelization report I get: `<line_number>, #pragma acc loop seq`

It appears that the compiler only takes into account the last line of the directive. Any idea why is this happening?

Running `pgc++ --version` gives the following:

`pgc++ 16.10-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp sandybridge`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using "device_type" correctly but we (PGI) are still missing a few OpenACC features including defining multiple loop schedules via the "device_type" clause.  The current limitations are listed in section 4.4 of the PGI release notes: http://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgirn-x64.pdf

Comment: Oh awesome! Thanks a lot for the reply my friend!