# OpenACC: DEVICE TYPE

Tags: gpu, openacc

I see a lot of functions, such as `acc_get_num_devices()`, requires as input the **device type**. I  used int `devtype=acc_get_device_type()` that returns devtype=2.

(In the documenation:
*acc_get_num_devices( devicetype )
Returns the number of devices of the specified type*)

What this 2 means? Which device types are there? Is device type an integer?

(Seems absurd to me I cannot find these info on the documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to section 2.4 of the [specification](https://www.openacc.org/sites/default/files/inline-files/OpenACC.2.7.pdf) for a general description of usage of `device_type`.  Also see Appendix A (not formally part of the specification) for recommendations for typical device types you might expect to encounter.

The `device_type` is used to specify a particular accelerator type, and it is **implementation defined**.  Therefore the specific types available for selection will be defined by the OpenACC aware compiler that you are using.

Using the PGI compiler implementation, the choices for `device_type` should correspond to the choices available for the `-ta=...` compiler switch.

A typical use of a `device_type` clause on an OpenACC directive is to (further) condition the behavior of that directive for specific device types.  For example, a specific optimization (such as choice of vector length to use) could be conditioned on running on a particular `device_type`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42346885/correct-use-of-device-type-in-openacc) is a particular (obsolete) example.  The device_type is used to either parallelize a particular loop, or run it sequentially, depending on device type that you are actually running on.  I say obsolete because I don't think `-ta=radeon` is a supported configuration for the most recent versions of the PGI OpenACC compilers (after 17.x).  You can see another example of usage of `device_type` in [this blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/getting-started-openacc/) and in [this blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/7-powerful-new-features-openacc-2-0/)

I believe in C/C++, the datatype is an enum type, whereas in Fortran it may formally be an integer.  Naturally in C/C++, an enum may have an underlying integer association. Rather than worrying about the meaning of a specific integer value in a specific implementation, it's probably better to use the enums/defines to refer to these.